# Is there a way to prevent postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, postback

As a continuation to as written here :
[Click on a button pauses other function interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62489483/click-on-a-button-pauses-other-function-interval?noredirect=1#comment110512574_62489483)

I've realized that clicking on a button / calling a JS function causes a postback, and it might be the reason that it is not possible to do them both together.

Is there any way to prevent this postback ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to stop the postback... 
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdatePlayersInPartyBTN" OnClientClick="javascript: return false;" onclick="UpdatePlayersInParty" />
Or
You can remove the runat server if you don't need it.

Comment: Why does return false would stop the postback action ?
I've tried doing as you suggested, and the postback stopped, and so is the counter, it is just stuck on 0.